Problem with Fetch user profile picture in Zoho cliq
I've to fetch the user details in Zoho cliq. But in response I'm not getting profile picture or it's url.
https://www.zoho.com/cliq/help/restapi/v2/#retrieve-particular-user
Above is the API documentation of Zoho cliq.
GET 
https://cliq.zoho.com/api/v2/users/{USER_ID}?fields=all 

Above is the REST api which I'm using to fetch the user detail.
In response Profile picture is not coming, I need the user profile picture.
Scope, authorization token, client id, client secret everything is correct and Zoho cliq API is also working.
Below is the response I'm getting from Zoho cliq. Am I missing something to fetch the profile picture. or Zoho cliq does not return profile picture in response?
Array
(
    [url] => /api/v2/users/12345678
    [data] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Dr.
            [user_org_status] => active
            [type] => paid
            [zoid] => 87654321
            [iamuid] => 12345678
            [organization_id] => 12345678
            [email_id] => drjohndoe@example.com
            [zuid] => 12345678
            [id] => 12345678
            [timeoffset] => 19800000
            [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata
            [language] => English
            [status] => active
            [country] => India
            [last_name] => John Doe
            [full_name] => Dr. John Doe
            [display_name] => Dr. John Doe
            [name] => Dr. John Doe
        )

)

